# Using same port for http/ ssh on two ip's

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, iptables, centos7

How could use two diferent services using the same port on two diferent IP addresses?

Example:

**IP 1 :  192.168.10.10:**

Service: Http Server

Ports: 443

**IP 2 :  192.168.10.11:**

Service: SSH Server

Port:  443

Comment: I would suggest making your question way more clear. Your missing about 80% of the information needed to answer it.

Comment: @Jeroen, sorry if i wasn't clear, i'll update the question.

Comment: I think he wants to have access from IP1 (from 80 or 443) to IP2 (on 443) using ssh protocol.

Comment: English isn't my primary language... so that's why i cant make myself very clear :\.

Comment: @cemdorst nop, basically i want to have ssh running under port 443 from the secondary ip, since the primary ip have a nginx server using 443.

Comment: Ok, still very confuse though. On your description you used the same address for both machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, for example, your IPs are `192.168.10.10` and `192.168.10.11`, and you want `sshd` to listen to port `443` on IP1, and `httpd` to Listen to port `443` on IP2:

Add to your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file:

```
ListenAddress 192.168.10.10:443
```

and restart SSH.  SSH will now listen on port 443 of IP1.

Add to your `httpd.conf` file (assuming Apache, should be easy with other httpd servers as well:

```
Listen 192.168.10.11:443
```

and restart httpd.  Apache will now listen on port 443 of IP2.

You don't mention what OS you are using, or what HTTP server you are using, so you may need to look for exact syntax or file locations for your system.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to segregate IP1 ==> NGINX and IP2 ==> SSHD, I suggest you to turn on NetFilter w/ PREROUTING : Nginx listen on 8443 and SSHD on 22 ; close these ports and PAT the 443 port regarding of the source.

Else, sorry, this isn't possible for one server to have two processes handling one Net socket (TCP/443), because the system couldn't know which process has to handle this or that kind of request.

What I imagine you can do :
 * Implement a sort of reverse proxy-like process to handle all requests and reroute it to `sushi` or `apache` ; I'm thinking about the old-fashioned **TCPMux** with `xinetd`, but it appears to be a dirty solution (actually as dirt as your request. Find infos [here](http://managing.blue/2010/12/20/tcpmux-a-mostly-overlooked-tcp-service/).
 * Far less dirty, implement some web-based SSH panel like **Gateone** downloadable [here](https://github.com/liftoff/GateOne).

Hope that it helped ?